# call an asynchronize function in the beginning of a component code

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react-native project.

I have a functional component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  
   // the checkData function is an asynchronize function
   const { checkData } = useContext(MyContext);

   // I have to wait for the result since the rendering part use the result as you can see below
   const isValid = await checkData();

   return (<View>
       <MySubComponent isValid={isValid}/> 
   </View>)
}
```

As you can see above, I have to call an asynchronize function `checkData` & using the result for rendering `MySubComponent`.  I can't use `await` like above code shows. I also tried making `MyComponent` an async functional component like `const MyComponent = async()=>{...}` but app crashes.

What is the correct way to call an asynchronize function in functional component & use its result for rendering sub component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to load `async` data and use a local state to track the value. for that you can try `useState` hook.

Set the initial value to `null` so you can show some kind of loading screen if the state is equal to `null`. If not ( That means `async` process updated the value to `true` or `false` ) then you can show the component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  
   // the checkData function is an asynchronize function
   const { checkData } = useContext(MyContext);
   const [isValid, setValidity] = useState(null);
   
   
   useEffect(() => {
     async function init() {
         const isValid = await checkData();
         setValidity(isValid);
     }
     init();
   }, [])

   return (
   <View>
       {isValid != null ? <MySubComponent isValid={isValid}/> : <SplashScreen />} 
   </View>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a `useEffect` and store `isValid` it in the state

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=> {
  const checkIfValid = async () => {
    const valid = await checkValid()
    setIsValid(valid)
  }
  checkIfValid();
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a variable, you could call `await checkData()` in a function and return its value, then call that function as the prop of `MySubComponent` like so:

```
const isValid = async () => {
    return await checkData();
}

return (
    <View>
        <MySubComponent isValid={isValid()} />
    </View>
);
```